# How to use array input for a custom GitHub Actions

Tags: arrays, github, github-actions

I'm working on a GitHub Action [workflow](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml/blob/4ea2062374784e3de840530c99365039f5fa76bb/action.yml#L47-L50) that uses an array for input.

I used this solution to simulate an array:

```yaml
      - uses: actions/my-custom-ci
        with:
          subdirectories: src/main/java src/test/java
```

But I want to use a solution like this:

```yaml
      - uses: actions/my-custom-ci
        with:
          subdirectories: 
                - src/main/java 
                - src/test/java
```

Is it possible to use an array input for custom GitHub Actions? If yes, how can we use an array input for custom GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, GitHub Actions doesn't support `array` types as input for actions. It only supports `string | number | boolean` (schema: [`with`](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/e7de43504da53808eb2a11de4f5baa64933e7176/src/schemas/json/github-workflow.json#L788) ref: [`definitions/env`](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/e7de43504da53808eb2a11de4f5baa64933e7176/src/schemas/json/github-workflow.json#L207)). So your approach is a valid workaround for now.

Just note that GitHub runners have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed by default, and GitHub Actions offers methods like [`fromJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson), [`toJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) and [`join`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#join), which may help you create a cleaner solution in case you want to generate a dynamic input of your custom action.

You can check [`google-github-actions/get-secretmanager-secrets`](https://github.com/google-github-actions/get-secretmanager-secrets)'s implementation where they [accept multiple inputs](https://github.com/google-github-actions/get-secretmanager-secrets#inputs) specified by line breaks, not as a `yaml` array:

```yaml
    - id: 'secrets'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/get-secretmanager-secrets@v1'
      with:
        secrets: |-
          token:my-project/docker-registry-token
          anotherOne:my-project/a-secret
          anotherOneToo:my-project/another-secret
```

Definitely, this might not be what you want to achieve. And it might not be worth refactoring your action. But it's a workaround for now.